# When I am trying to connect from my localhost and perform operations, it's working, but the server running on EKS gives the above error

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-rds, amazon-eks

dial tcp: lookup simple-bank.cejetrykwn68.ap-south-1.rds.amazonaws.com on 10.100.0.10:53: read udp 172.31.13.150:39956->10.100.0.10:53: read: connection refused

getting this problem when I am connecting to the database through the server

Comment: Hi. Your question requires more clarity. Please add your network configuration to the question to start with

Answer (score 0):

The error message you provided appears that there is a problem with the DNS resolution or network connectivity when attempting to connect to the database server.

Try the following commands to ensure your connection:

```
    nslookup simple-bank.cejetrykwn68.ap-south-1.rds.amazonaws.com

    or

    ping simple-bank.cejetrykwn68.ap-south-1.rds.amazonaws.com
```